# How to configure SSL on SearX with step by step installation from SearX documentation?

Tags: ssl

I install searx on my server with this instruction:
https://searx.github.io/searx/admin/installation-searx.html#installation-basic

I use default setting and change bind_address into my domain name. It works.

Now I have no hint how to configure SSL on my SearX installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my fault, Installing using nginx is the next step for installation, not another new fresh installation method.
I'm getting clear now after seeing this diagram:
https://searx.github.io/searx/admin/architecture.html#arch-public

That mean I can create ssl in nginx and using proxy for searx.